# ListView doesn't display data in xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin and trying to display a listview. My attempt is as follows.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ComListView" RowHeight="80">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <Grid Margin="8">
                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="hello world" FontAttributes="Bold"  />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

But when I ran the app, even I navigate to correct page; nothing display. For any other views, it will display the right output. So where could I get wrong on the listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put items to the `ListView`. Currently, you only specify the `ItemTemplate`, which determines how an item will look (in your case, they will all look the same (i.e. Labels with 'hello world' text)). But the `ListView` is empty and so there are no items to show.

You can set items using the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView`.

Usually, you use `Binding` inside an `ItemTemplate` to show item content.

Let's say we have a class `Person`:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create a `List` of `Person` objects and add it to your `ListView` in code:

```
var personnel = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "Booker" },
    new Person { Name = "Elizabeth" }
};

ComListView.ItemsSource = personnel;
```

And in your XAML, you have to set the `ItemTemplate` so that it shows the `Name` of each `Person`:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Note: You can also bind to `ItemsSource` from XAML if you have a ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding the data to the listview.
use the ItemSource property to bind data, either from xaml, code behind or use a binding to populate from your ViewModel